# How to format JS Date as a C# compatible DateTime?

Tags: javascript, c#, date, datetime, format

I've passed a Javascript DateTime picker date from a view to an MVC controller action.

The format of the string when passed to the controller action is `Thu Jul 28 2016 17:05:00 GMT+0100` which causes an `invalid operation exception converting String to DateTime.` in C#.

This is how I assign the value of the Date picker to the hidden field value:

```
$('#OutageStart').val(e.date)
```

How can you format JS Date string as a C# compatible DateTime?

The binding error is thrown in the C# custom model binder that tries to bind the JS Date string value to a `Nullable<DateTime>`:

```
public class DateTimeBinder : System.Web.Mvc.IModelBinder
{


    public object BindModel(ControllerContext controllerContext, System.Web.Mvc.ModelBindingContext bindingContext)
    {
        var value = bindingContext.ValueProvider.GetValue(bindingContext.ModelName);
        bindingContext.ModelState.SetModelValue(bindingContext.ModelName, value);

        return value.ConvertTo(typeof(DateTime), CultureInfo.CurrentCulture);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is the format of a "C# compatible DateTime"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

alternatively you can use timestamp for the conversion and user's timezone won't effect your result

in js

```
myDateObject.getTime() //-> outputs a timestamp (integer)
```

in c# (if you have .NET 4.6+)

```
DateTimeOffset.FromUnixTimeSeconds(timestamp);
```

otherwise

```
System.DateTime dtDateTime = new DateTime(1970,1,1,0,0,0,0,System.DateTimeKind.Utc);
dtDateTime = dtDateTime.AddSeconds(timestamp).ToLocalTime();
```

Comment: ok so on the JS side,I tried doing the following but dev tools console told me e.getTime is not a function?  

`$("#OutageStartDisplay").on("dp.change", function (e) {

            $('#OutageStart').val(e.getTime());

}`

Comment: @BrianJ try e.date.getTime()

Answer (score 0):

In js

```
Var date = $.datepicker.formatdate('dd/mm/yy',new Date(datepickerdate)
```

In c#

```
Void convertdate(string javascriptdateinstringformat){
datetime.parse(javascriptdateinstringformat) ; }`
```

Comment: Are you sure *$.datepicker.formatdate* is part of javascript or are you depending on one or more libraries for that functionality?

Comment: It's a date picker library function. And u r using date picker aren't u?     I have implement it and it's working fine from last many months .

Comment: It fits with the technologies inferred by the question, but nice to note that it's not part of javascript. The OP hasn't tagged the question with the libraries being used, so others stumbling across this answer may be confused as to why it doesn't work for them. ;-) Oh, whether I'm using "date picker" is irrelevant.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using new Date() function ? In normal binding this works but in your custom value i'm not sure but do try if this could help.

> $('#OutageStart').val(new Date(e.date));

Comment: Didn't work, adds the full name of the timezone to the Date string.